# Input form validation needed

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, validation

I need help for my input form validation. I don't get error messages all at once but appears only at the first text of name 'first name'

My HTML code:

```
<body>

    <img id="logo2" src="logo2.jpg">

    <div id="request-container">

            <h2>REQUEST A DEMO</h2>

            <div id="request">

                <p>First Name *</p>
                <input id="1"  type="text">
                <span id="empty"></span>

                <p>Last Name *</p>
                <input id="2" type="text">
                <span id="empty"></span>

                <p>Email *</p>
                <input id="3"  type="email">
                <span id="empty"></span>

                <p>Phone *</p>
                <input id="4" type="tel">
                <span id="empty"></span>

                <p>Company Name *</p>
                <input id="5"  type="text">
                <span id="empty"></span>

                <p>Company Website *</p>
                <input id="6" type="email">
                <span id="empty"></span>

                <p>Country *</p>
                    <select id="country">
                        <option></option>
                        <option>India</option>
                        <option>USA</option>
                        <option>Canade</option>
                        <option>Australia</option>
                        <option>China</option>
                        <option>South Africa</option>
                        <option>Russia</option>
                        <option>Germany</option>
                    </select>
                <span id="empty"></span>

                <div id="demo" onclick="return validateForm()">Schedule a Demo!</div>

            </div>


    </div>
```

My JavaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function validateForm()
    {
        var ok=true;
        var first=document.getElementById('1').value;
        var last=document.getElementById('2').value;
        var email=document.getElementById('3').value;
        var phone=document.getElementById('4').value;
        var company=document.getElementById('5').value;
        var website=document.getElementById('6').value;

        if (first == "" || first== null) 
            {
                    document.getElementById('empty').innerHTML="This field is required";
                    ok=false;

            }

        if (last == ""|| last== null) 
            {
                    document.getElementById('empty').innerHTML="This field is required";    
                    ok= false;

            }

        if (email == ""|| email== null) 
            {   
                    document.getElementById('empty').innerHTML="This field is required";    
                    ok=false;

            }

        if (phone == "" || phone==null) 
            {
                    document.getElementById('empty').innerHTML="This field is required";
                    ok= false;

            }

        if (company == ""|| company== null) 
            {
                    document.getElementById('empty').innerHTML="This field is required";
                    ok= false;

            }

        if (website == ""|| website== null) 
            {
                    document.getElementById('empty').innerHTML="This field is required";
                    ok= false;

            }


        return ok;

    }

        document.getElementById('demo').onclick = function  () 

        {
            validateForm();
        }

    </script>
```

Comment: Why does every `if` block do exactly the same thing?

Comment: Also, your HTML is invalid.  `id`s need to be *unique*.  The behavior of the code is undefined until the markup is correct.

Comment: Just use `required` attribute on `<input>`.

Comment: It is checking for empty fields in all the input text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as David said, you need your IDs which you placed in those spans to be unique. You also need to reference those unique IDs from you JavaScript. Also, there's no point in defining onclick twice. So, for example, you can keep the onclick definition once in your HTML tag like so

```
<input id="demo" type="button" value="Schedule a Demo!" onclick="return validateForm()">
```

and delete the other occurrence where you have onclick defined, which is the following in your JavaScript code:

```
document.getElementById('demo').onclick = function  ()

{
    validateForm();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying.And lastly when the error messages arrives the position of all the elements inside the div changes.Any help for that

Comment: Np. Are you sure that you changed those span IDs to unique IDs in the HTML, then updated each corresponding getElementById() calls in your JavaScript to correctly map to the unique IDs you created in your HTML (as we said in our answers to your question)? There will be no such error if you did that. I did it myself, and it works on the code you provided.

Comment: Let me know how it goes, and be sure to mark the best answer as accepted (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: I got that.But I am asking about the positioning of all the element inside the div changes which appears outside my black colored div once all the error message arrives.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean and I believe your original question has already been answered, but.... [This link](https://imagebin.ca/v/2esQOHGpeZe1) shows how it looks for me. How did you expect it to look?

Comment: okk...It looks perfectly fine in your link..But in mine I want the error msg "this field is required" below the text box.And when it appears below the text box the elements like the "country' and last button"schedule a demo" appear below the form or you can say outside the div box.So any way you can tell how the elements can stay in position without going outside the div box.

Comment: Sure, that's a 30-sec fix. [Is this](https://imagebin.ca/v/2etMzs4f8WFU) what you were looking for? Look into using more divs, maybe look at some html div tutorials off of google/W3Schools, etc. A way to do it is to wrap divs around the sections that are desired to basically have some kind of invisible box around them. So then you can style the divs using the CSS style tag, or it might just work how the default div styling is, to get the text where you want it in relation to each div. When I did it, I just threw in some <div>{your other html}</div> tags with no extra attributes or styles etc.

Comment: If you still can't get it, let me know what you've tried and I'll try to steer you in the right direction.

Comment: Hey thanks.Got it the way I wanted it.I just took fields(firstname<p>,<input><span>) into a div and gave  a height to it so that they all stay together and also increased the height of the whole container.Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help out!

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that your `id` values aren't unique, which they need to be according to HTML specifications.  And according to reason, really.  After all, which element in your markup *should* this be referencing?:

```
document.getElementById('empty')
```

Use meaningful (and *unique*) identifiers.  For example:

```
<p>First Name *</p>
<input id="firstNameInput" type="text">
<span id="firstNameMessage"></span>
```

Then update the code to use those identifiers:

```
var first=document.getElementById('firstNameInput').value;
//...
if (first == "" || first== null) 
{
    document.getElementById('firstNameMessage').innerHTML = "This field is required";
    ok=false;
}
```

Repeat for your other elements.

Comment: Got it.Thank you!!.And lastly when the error messages arrives the position of all the elements inside the div changes.Any help for that.